# Spring + Ajax Post data text

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using a post Ajax to call a controller, however i do not get a response and get error.

I see that the controller also gets null on the user name where ajax get properly Below is my code

Ajax is hitting the controller and the input value (username) is print as null in the systemout, hence not getting the expected value

My Spring Controller

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {

UserService userService;
@Autowired
public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@PostMapping("/api/search")
public String getSearchResultViaAjax(String username) {
    System.out.println(username);
    String result=userService.findByNativeByName(username);
    return result;

}
}
```

My Ajax which submits post

```
function fire_ajax_submit() {
   var name = $("#username").val();
    $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", true);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "text/plain",
    url: "/api/search",
    data: name,
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function (data) {
        var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
            data + "</pre>";
        $('#feedback').html(json);
        console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
        $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    error: function (e) {

        var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
            + e.responseText + "</pre>";
        $('#feedback').html(json);
        console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});

}
```

My html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="search-form">
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
   <fieldset>
      <p>
         <select id = "username" class="form-control">
           <option value = "Kilu">Kilu</option>
           <option value = "Maha">Maha</option>
         </select>
      </p>
   </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) annotation on `getSearchResultViaAjax`?

Comment: @Sam i tried that too and still have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

1) Your Spring Controller should be @RestController or @Controller with method annotated as @ResponseBody.

2) Post data like this ==> data: { "username": name },

3) After receiving the data, use stringify() to display it, and use JSON.parse() to extract the value.

4) Check your Content type header parameter(contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;')

Answer (score 0):

Try passing data like below :

```
 data: { "username": name },
```

Comment: data: { "name": name },    Still gives same error of no response

Comment: are you sure ajax is hitting the controller and you are getting the value and your controller is returning something but not null?..confirm all 3 first.

Comment: Ajax is hitting the controller and the input value (username) is print as null in the systemout, hence not getting the expected value

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a  "**,**" (**comma**) after your **success block** ,otherwise you will keep on getting the same error on your page on console  :-

```
success: function (data) {

       //your code

    },  // right here to indicate the end of this block here as you're putting your error block after this.
```

Comment: i'm able to get the response now. However, if i print response, it prints data{"username":"Danish"}. How to get the value "Danish" alone?

Comment: @kulumakani in order to do that, get/parse your **'username'** or **result** (or whatever variable name you're using in response from controller) from the 'data' into Json String in your ajax-success function, something like this : ---

 success: function (data) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data.result)); 
}

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the contentType,

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;'
```

And also put ','(comma) after the success block.